# I create a class witch is child of another class in a the same namespace. but Visual Studio can not identify protected field in the parent class

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApp35
{
    class Student
    {
        protected string fName;
        protected string lName;
        protected string sNumber;
    }

    class BachlorStudent : Student
    {
        //I can't write  fName="abc";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add some method then you can write as mentioned below.

```
namespace ConsoleApp35
{
    class Student
    {
        protected string fName;
        protected string lName;
        protected string sNumber;
    }

    class BachlorStudent : Student
    {
        private void method1()
        {
            fName = "abc";
        }
    }
}
```